# why dd++/d++ does not work in (non dynamically allocated arrays)?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion, pointer-arithmetic

hey I am a beginner in C and I am trying to understand pointers
I created a program in which I decay a pointer d in the array arr1 and after that i deacay a pointer to pointer dd in  d pointer .
My purpose is to print the words with the use of pointer to pointer in a non dynamically allocated array .
The first program prints all the words
The second program prints only the first line
The third program prints the first line and some strange symbols
I know it is a unsual way but I was curious why d++ or dd++ does not work in a non dynamically allocated array?

first program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    int i=0;
    char arr1[5][10]={"ball","wall","window","table","tv"};
    

    printf("\n");



    char *d;
    char **dd=&d;
    for(i=0; i<5; ++i){
        d=arr1[i];
        printf("array[%d] contains: %s\n", i, *dd);
    }

return 0;
}
```

second program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main ()
{
    
    int i=0;
    char arr1[5][10]={"ball","wall","window","table","tv"};
    printf("\n");
    char *d;
    d=&arr1[0][0];
    char **dd;
    dd=&d;
    for(dd=&d ; *dd ; dd++)
    {
        printf("\nthe words are %s",*dd); 
        d++; 
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

third program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main ()
{
    
    int i=0;
    char arr1[5][10]={"ball","wall","window","table","tv"};
    printf("\n");
    char *d;
    d=&arr1[0][0];
    char **dd;
    dd=&d;
    for(dd=&d ; *dd ; dd++)
    {
        printf("\nthe words are %s",*dd); 
         
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your text ask about `d++` but that's not in your code...!?

Comment: @4386427 Excuse me I edited now

Answer (score 0):

`dd` starts by pointing to `d`. The **value`of`d`is the address of`arr1`so when you dereference`dd`, you get a pointer to the start of the array and you can use that pointer to print the word "ball". That's fine.

But when you increment `dd` the first time using `dd++` it will point to the location just after `d`. That position has nothing to do with the array and there is no `char*` at that location, so dereferencing `dd` is undefined bahavior.

In other words, `dd++` makes no sense as `d` is a single char pointer.

BTW: Notice that you also have two `dd++` in your loop.

Comment: @4386427I understand what you say I had not noticed that I take 2 times the dd++ 
Now I clarify it

Answer (score 0):

In the first program the pointer `d` in each iteration of the for loop is assigned with the address of the first character of each string stored in the array arr1.

```
for(i=0; i<5; ++i){
    d=arr1[i];
    ^^^^^^^^^^
    printf("array[%d] contains: %s\n", i, *dd);
}
```

At the same time the value stored in the pointer `dd` is not being changed The pointer `dd` is still point to the pointer `d`.

In the second program the pointer `dd` is initialized by the address of the pointer `d`. But after incrementing the pointer dd will point to the memory after the pointer `d`. And as a result the for loop has undefined behavior.

```
d=&arr1[0][0];
char **dd;
dd=&d;
for(dd=&d ; *dd ; dd++)
                  ^^^^
{
    printf("\nthe words are %s",*dd); 
    d++; 
}
```

This statement in the loop

```
    d++;
```

does not affect the pointer `dd` because after incrementing the pointer `dd` it does not already point to the pointer `d`.

The same problem exists in the third program. That is after incrementing the pointer dd in the for loo

```
for(dd=&d ; *dd ; dd++)
```

it points to the memory beyond the pointer d and using the expression *dd invokes undefined behavior.

You can use the following approach of using a pointer to output strings stored in a two-dimensional character array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    char arr1[][N] = { "ball", "wall", "window", "table", "tv" };
    
    const size_t M = sizeof( arr1 ) / sizeof( *arr1 );
    
    for ( char ( *d )[N] = arr1; d != arr1 + M; ++d )
    {
        puts( *d );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
ball
wall
window
table
tv
```

That is array designator used in expressions with rare exceptions is converted to a pointer to its first element.

As the array `arr1` has the type `char[5][10]` then the element type of the array is `char[10]`. A pointer to an object of such type will have the type `char ( * )[10]`. Incrementing the pointer it will point to the next element of the array. Dereferencing this pointer as it is shown in the demonstrative program

```
puts( *d );
```

we get the pointed element that is an array of the type `char[10]`. But used in an expression as for example as the argument of the call of puts it is in turn is converted to pointer to the first element of the array (string) and has the type `char *`.

Comment: I understand what you say but I noticed something else that you use `const size_t` instead of `size_t` why you did this?

Comment: @Βill97 As the array arr1 has a fixed size then it is natural to declare the variable M as a constant variable because the size of the array will not be changed within the program.